# TreeMap sort is not working on equal values

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, comparator, treemap

I have written a method that sorts the `TreeMap` by its values

```
public TreeMap<String, Integer> sortByValues(final TreeMap<String, Integer> map) {
        Comparator<String> valueComparator =  new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String k1, String k2) {
                int compare = map.get(k1).compareTo(map.get(k2));
                return compare;
            }
        };
        Map<String, Integer> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(valueComparator);
        sortedByValues.putAll(map);
        return sortedByValues;
    }
```

The above method works fine in normal case but fails when there is a duplicate value present in the TreeMap. Any duplicate value entry is removed from the Map.After googling it I found the solution as

```
public Map<String, Integer> sortByValuesTree(final Map<String, Integer> map) {
        Comparator<String> valueComparator =  new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String k1, String k2) {
                int compare = map.get(k1).compareTo(map.get(k2));
                if (compare == 0) return 1;
                else return compare;
            }
        };
        Map<String, Integer> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(valueComparator);
        sortedByValues.putAll(map);
        return sortedByValues;
    }
```

The above works fine but I am not able to understand why first method didn't work. Why did it remove duplicate value entry? Can someone please let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why did it remove duplicate value entry?

Because that's the very definition of a Map: for a given key, it stores one value. If you put another value for a key that is already in the map, the new value replaces the old one for this key. And since you told the map that a key is equal to another one when their associated value are equal, the map considers two keys to be equal when their value are equal.

Note that your solution is a bad one which probably works by accident. Indeed, your comparator doesn't respect the contract of the Comparator interface. Indeed, when two values are equal, you arbitrarily decide to make the first one bigger than the second one. This means that your comparator makes A > B and B > A true at the same time, which is not correct.

Sorting a TreeMap by value just looks like an absurdity to me. You won't be able to add any new value to the map anyway, since it would require the entry to already exist in the old map. Shouldn't you simply have a sorted list of map entries?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, in Java 7+, the OP's comparator is likely to break (it uses timsort rather than mergesort). Java 6 and below is somewhat more tolerant of broken comparators. I know this from first-hand experience when doing our Java 7 migration project; our broken comparators were discovered very quickly when tests started becoming red. :-)

Comment: @JB Nizet-I was asked this in an interview, so wanted to try it.

Comment: @Anand Then your code will flunk the interview for violating a basic comparator rule.

Comment: @JB Nizet - I still don't understand it.My keys are all different but two values are same.My method is comparing based on the values not keys. Could you or Chris please throw some light on it

Comment: @Anand For the purposes of determining distinctness, a `TreeMap` will _only_ consider what the comparator returns, and when it returns 0, the elements are considered equivalent. It does not call `equals` on the keys.

Comment: A TreeMap sorts its entries by keys. What you're doing is telling the Map: key "a" and key "b" are equal because "a" is associated with the value 45 and "b" is also associated with the value 45. When two keys are equal, the Map considers they're a unique key, and thus only one value can be associated with that key. The comparator is not only used for sorting. It's use to determine when two keys are equal. And two keys are equal when the comparator returns 0 when comparing these two keys.

Comment: @JBNizet/@Chris - So many thanks..I got it now..Just one more thing which sorting mechanism does TreeMap use?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, especially in Java 7 onwards, even your second method is not going to work. (See below for why.) Anyway, the reason is that maps must have distinct keys, and when you are using your value as key, two equal values would be treated as equal keys.

The proper fix, by the way, is to sort by value, then by key:

```
int compare = map.get(k1).compareTo(map.get(k2));
if (compare == 0) {
    compare = k1.compareTo(k2);
}
return compare;
```

---

Proper comparators must follow three rules:

1. `compare(a, a) == 0` for all values of `a`.
2. `signum(compare(a, b)) == -signum(compare(b, a))` for all values of `a` and `b`.
3. if `signum(compare(a, b)) == signum(compare(b, c))`, then `signum(compare(a, c))` must also have the same value, for all values of `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: I am running on Java 7 but it is working fine the second method

Comment: Then, like JB Nizet's answer says, it only works by accident. Don't make your program fragile! Write a proper comparator. Your second method broke rule 2.